# How to keep WSL2 running after closing ssh on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I connect to a Windows pc with `ssh` and use `WSL2` which installed in the PC.

The problem is that `WSL2` is terminated when I disconnect `ssh` to the PC(Windows).

I need a way to keep `WSL2` running after disconnecting `ssh` on Windows 10.

How could I do this?

Comment: Have you tried using `tmux` on `WSL2`? Allows you to create a terminal session that persists even after `ssh` is disconnected.

Comment: Can you show how you did SSH ? Did you SSH into WSL2 directly ? If yes, that means ssh daemon was running before your SSH. If you disconnect SSH, the ssh daemon should be still running so WSL2 will not be terminated.

Comment: @wxz I used screen but wsl2 was terminated.

Comment: @Philippe I ssh into windows 10.

Comment: I didn't know WSL worked like a traditional app, I thought it worked more like a daemon that stays on all the time. Good to know.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm that launching tmux within wsl2 ubuntu instance and then detach tmux session via pressing `prefix` then `d` works. Prefix is `ctrl + b` by default. After doing this, the instance is kept alive even I exit the terminal window or ssh login.